# setting model values from a vuejs 2.0 directive

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using a Vue 2.0 directive to apply a Twitter Typeahead to the input.  I've been able to get it to apply the value back to the Vue model in a way that feels like a bit of a hack, *by looping through the context, finding the parent object and calling my method `setAutocmpleteValue()`*

HTML setup for Vue Custom Directive

```
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search" name='typeahead'
        v-typeahead="getFieldValues(part.fieldName)"  
        v-model="part.value" v-bind:value="part.value"
        v-on:change="updateTest()" @input="onValidChange()" />
```

Custom Directive

```
Vue.directive('typeahead', {
    inserted:  function(el_, binding,v) {
         // this feels like a hack, is there a better way?
         v.context._self.parent.setAutocmpleteValue('test');
     }
})
```

Within a directive $emit is not available to pass an event, is there a better way to call `setAutocmpleteValue()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Vue 2, directives are intended [for DOM manipulation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

> Note that in Vue 2.0, the primary form of code reuse and abstraction
> is components - however there may be cases where you just need some
> low-level DOM access on plain elements, and this is where custom
> directives would still be useful.

They are not intended for setting data values and attempts to do so will rely on hacks like you are using.

Not only that, but this is a very fragile approach. The directive in the question is dependent on a method in the parent of the current context. What if the input element was two levels down or more?

You're much better off implementing a component.

However, given you are already hacking, $emit is available from the `context`.

```
v.context.$emit("some-event", someData)
```

The `context` is the Vue or Vue component containing the element to which you have attached the directive, so you would want to listen to it from the parent of that component.